# Why the for loop in this program is indefinite?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>                                        

int main()
{
    unsigned char ch; 

    for (ch=0; ch<=255; ch++)   
        printf ("\n%d %c", ch, ch); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loop goes as such:

1. Initialize
2. Check condition
3. Do body
4. Do post action (increment in your case)
5. Go to 2.

You have declared:

```c
unsigned char ch;
```

Range for such a variable would be [0..255]. So the problem is once it hits 255 it goes into body since 255<=255 afterwards it gets incremented and becomes 0, which is again fine since 0<=255. Hence it is an infinite loop.

Comment: There is a doubt that when 'ch' gets incremented to 255, the condition is still satisfied then the printf ( ) should give 255 and the corresponding character and after that 'ch' gets incremented to 256 and now the condition becomes false and loop should be simply terminated. Please clarify..

Comment: @daya unsigned char is a single byte unsigned type, which may hold values from 0 up to 2^8-1, on the majority of systems values get wrapped around on overflow (although that is an undefined behaviour, if I'm not mistaken). Your printf is the culprit for your misunderstanding, neither %d nor %c are the valid specifier for an unsigned char, use %u instead.

Comment: thanks for clearing doubt.

Answer (score 4):

Since `ch` is of type `unsigned char`, it can only contain values between 0 and 255. When you increment `ch` from 255, it wraps around to 0, so it's always less than or equal to 255 and thus the loop continues forever.